# jQuery loop through Child divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, html, each

```
<div id="ChosenCategory" class="chosen">
   <div class="cat_ch" name="1">
   <div class="cat_ch" name="2">
   <div class="cat_ch" name="3">
   <div class="cat_ch" name="5">
   <div class="clear"> </div>
</div>
```

I want to loop though `div.cat_ch` How?

This one fails:

```
    $("div").each(function () {
       alert("FW");
       alert($(this).attr("name").val());
    });
```

Comment: Looks like a list. Therefore, should be UL/LI, not DIV/DIV. Also, the "clear" DIV can be avoided if you set `overflow:auto` on the parent.

Comment: $('.cat_ch').each(function(){});

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `name` is not a valid attribute of a `div` element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/2TRxh/

I think your issue lies with the attempt to get the val off the div after you get the attribute `$(this).attr("name").val()`. Using `.val()` on a div doesn't make sense. If you remove that `$(this).attr("name")` returns the `name` property off the divs. You can further specify the div's to loop through by using the class selector in your each rather than just div. `$(".cat_ch").each(function () {});` This has been shown in various other answers to this question.

Answer (score 16):

```
$('#ChosenCategory').children('.cat_ch').each(function() {

});
```

Or

```
$('#ChosenCategory > .cat_ch').each(function() {

});
```

JQuery's `.children` method and css3 child selector `>` will return only the direct children that match the selector, class `.cat_ch` in the example.

If you want to search deeper in the DOM tree, that is, include nested elements, use `.find` or omit the child selector:

```
$('#ChosenCategory').find('.cat_ch').each( function(){} )
```

Or

```
$('#ChosenCategory .cat_ch').each( function(){} )
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$(function(){

    var items=$(".cat_ch")
     $.each(items,function (index,item) {

       alert($(item).attr("name"));
    });

});
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/GzKHA/

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to target the Divs inside, try

```
$('#ChosenCategory div').each( function() {...} );
```

The other answers require specific classes and/or will also process non-divs within your parent div.

Comment: Be warned! This will also hit your "clear" div, you can avoid that by doing $('#ChosenCategory div:not(.clear)') instead

Comment: Yeah, why don't you then change the selector to `$('#ChosenCategory div.cat_ch')` ?

Comment: Although the OP did have those classes on there, the question was really phrased as "loop through child divs," so I wanted to give an answer that reflected how to loop through child divs regardless of their names. Page layout often changes in the development of an app, and sometimes it's nice to not have to rewrite your javascript just to match different selectors.

Answer (score 2):

```
    function loopOver(obj)
    {
        var chl=obj.firstChild;
        while(chl)
        {
            if(chl.nodeType==1)
            {
                var isAttr=chl.getAttribute('name');
                if(isAttr)
                {
                    alert(isAttr);
                }
            }
            chl=chl.nextSibling;
        }
    }

    //This is by far the fastest in terms of execution speed!!!
    var obj=document.getElementById("ChosenCategory");
    loopOver(obj);
```

```
Make sure to enclose the each `<div>` tag at the end of each!!
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".cat_ch").each(function () {
       alert("FW");
       alert($(this).attr("name").val());
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to loop through `div.cat_ch`, you should use that for the jQuery selector:

```
$("div.cat_ch").each(function () {
   alert("FW");
   alert($(this).attr("name").val());
});
```

You can also loop through the child elements by using the jQuery `children()` method:

```
$("#ChosenCategory").children().each(function () {
   alert("FW");
   alert($(this).attr("name").val());
});
```

A third way to loop through the desired elements is like so:

```
$("#ChosenCategory > div").each(function () {
   alert("FW");
   alert($(this).attr("name").val());
});
```

Use whichever way you want, there is no best way.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.cat_ch').each(function(i, e) {
    alert('FW');
    alert(e.attr('name').val());
});
```